# Send touches on iOS device to another UIScreen (external display)

Tags: iphone, ipad

Is there a simple way to send touches on an iOS device (e.g. iPad) to another UIScreen which is rendered on an external display?

For example, the iPad shows a blank screen and the app is shown on the external screen. If I touch down on the iPad approximately where the button (displayed on the other UIScreen) would be, it sends the coordinates to the other UIScreen so that it looks like I'm touching down on it.

This is intended to be a quick way to output what would normally be displayed on an iPad, to an external display, but still retain touch interactivity. It's somewhat an alternative to app mirroring.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible if you want to submit your app to the App Store as it will rejected by Apple for using private APIs, because there are no public methods to create UITouch objects.

However this can be done with private APIs, there is an [article here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone.html) which shows how to do it.